# angular firestore has no exported member DATABASE_URL

Tags: angular, angularfire

Hi I am upgrading my angular app and I am facing the below issue
When I am using angular fire version 6.0.1 I get DATABASE_URL related error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:16:3 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/projects/ac node/firestore-phone-app/node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/angular-fire-firestore"' has no exported member 'DATABASE_URL'.

16   DATABASE_URL
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "7.13.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
```

when i use @angular/fire: 6.0.2 I get error

```
ERROR in getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected AngularFireModule to have an inner class declaration
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `packages.json` file, put this version:

```
"@angular/fire": "6.0.0",
```

Comment: Thanks but still gives error DATABASE_URL is not exported member